# How connect few workflows to make them working like one bigger?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, design

I need to split my workflow into few smallers and make them work in the same way like one bigger. How can i do it?

I use SharePoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a flag column which will be checked by each workflow. Based on flag value, you can execute further steps in workflow.

'Wait for field change" action can be used to wait for field change in current item. At end of each workflow, update the flag value to trigger next workflow execution.

Comment: Thank you. And which start options should I mark for workflow2, workflow3 etc. ?

Comment: Start options depends on your requirement - if workflow needs on new item, mark all workflow on "new item creation". Similarly for edit item. Ideally all workflow should be started at once but should wait for field change.